# Java Script Button.onclick doesnt'work if wrapped in div

Tags: javascript, html

In my project I need to create button dynamically. I wrap it to div and this div is appended to container  called tableDoc. My problem is that in this case `onclick` function doesn't work.
If my button is appended straight to tableDoc with not being wrapped to div before it works fine.

Could you tell me why `onclick` function doesn't work if wrapped to div?

Example with button wrapped to div before being added to tableDoc:

```
 Elements.map(item=>{
           
            const div=document.createElement('div');
            ///////adding button////////////////
            var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

            deleteButton.setAttribute('type','button');
            deleteButton.setAttribute('class',"btn-close");
            deleteButton.setAttribute('aria-label','Close');
            deleteButton.setAttribute('id',item.pk);
            deleteButton.onclick = function() { 
            alert("blabla");
          };
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            div.innerHTML+=item.fields.car+'  '+item.fields.model
            div.appendChild(deleteButton); 
            tableDoc.appendChild(div);
            div.innerHTML+='<br>'


            })
```

secondary example with button added straight to tableDoc:

```
Elements.map(item=>{
           
            const div=document.createElement('div');
            ///////adding button////////////////
            var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

            deleteButton.setAttribute('type','button');
            deleteButton.setAttribute('class',"btn-close");
            deleteButton.setAttribute('aria-label','Close');
            deleteButton.setAttribute('id',item.pk);
            deleteButton.onclick = function() { 
            alert("blabla");
          };
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            div.innerHTML+=item.fields.car+'  '+item.fields.model
            tableDoc.appendChild(deleteButton);
            tableDoc.appendChild(div);
            div.innerHTML+='<br>'


            })
```

Comment: what is Elements?

Comment: Elements is my ajax response

Comment: not helpful. show structure

Comment: With the code you've shown there is no way it's related to that. You are clearly **not** appending the button to the `div` in your second code example : `tableDoc.appendChild(deleteButton);`

Comment: @connexo, see this line in first example `div.appendChild(deleteButton);` paired with `div.innerHTML+='<br>'` is losing the event listener *in translation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the event listener by using `div.innerHTML+='<br>'`.

In the below example, I am creating 2 buttons and append them to 2 divs.
The only difference here is that afterwards, I use `innerHTML` on one of the divs which causes the button to lose its event listener.

That's because `innerHTML` is a text based function and doesn't carry event listeners with. It operates only on the string representation of the node.

```js
const fooButton = document.createElement('button')
fooButton.onclick = () => console.log("foo")
fooButton.textContent = "foo"
document.getElementById("foo").append(fooButton)

const barButton = document.createElement('button')
barButton.onclick = () => console.log("bar")
barButton.textContent = "bar"
document.getElementById("bar").append(barButton)
document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML += '<br>'
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: OP is appending the button to  `tableDoc`, not to the `div`. So with the code OP has shown it can't be related to that.

Comment: Look close at their code, first example it's appending to the div and the div to the table doc, and then they use innerHTML on that div. Second one directly to the table doc. And that is also the problem they described.